# Reading files inside a APK

Tags: java, android

I am having an android application that is using an external jar that 
has in addition to regular classes an html file.

Meaning my final apk root directory looks something like this

- assests
- res
- AndroidManifest.xml
- classes.dex
- resources.arsc
- helloworld.html

How can I access from my application to the last file 
"helloworld.html"?

Comment: Can you save html file inside the assets and then call "getAssets()" ?

Answer (score 1):

Android package hierarchy is not a like java application package.
So you can't access files like this.

I think you have to use this **helloworld.html** file in your application.

So put this file in `/asset` directory and in your activity code just get file using

`getAssets()`.

also access file like: `file:///android_asset/helloworld.html`

Comment: This is not what I want. I am giving developers a jar, and i want them just to use the jar, and not tell them - "in addition, please put this html file in your assets directory"

Comment: My answer is related to your question.. "How can I access from my application to the last file "helloworld.html"?"

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The html file is NOT in the assets directory

Comment: What do you want to achieve? just clarify your question so other user also can help you.

Comment: I am developing an SDK for other android developers. Part of the sdk is some static html files. I want developers to have minimum integration, meaning just add my jar to their classpath. I can send them in addition the jar file a bunch of html files and tell them to put them in their assets directory.  But i want to avoid that, but still have the ability to access those html files.

Comment: Whats the use of those html files?

Comment: You have to put those file is asset of your jar files.. No other option.. Sorry.. Also if possible put those html files in asset of your jar file then write code for copy those file into internal storage of application package and load those files form internal storage. then your developers have to nothing to do.

Comment: I don't want my developer to have a special build process. And my jar file can't have resource or assets files. I think this is going to be changed in the next Android Sdk Tools. Anyhow I've found my solution.

I would post it here as an answer, but i can't due to low reputation . But in general, I am reading my apk file
`packagePath = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0).sourceDir;`
And then by using the class `java.util.zip.ZipFile` I retrieve the html file, and copy it to `context.getFilesDir().getPath()`.

Comment: Both the cases are same, anyway choice is yours. Happy coding..!

Comment: You can put the content of those html files into your java source code file. Then you can do whatever you want by call your java function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not making a library project instead of a jar?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the string "`assets/SecureManifest.xml`" with your file "`helloworld.html`"

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromApkResource(String apkFilePath, String apkResPath) throws IOException {
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(apkFilePath);
    JarEntry jarEntry = jarFile.getJarEntry(apkResPath);
    return jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
}

// Example usage reading the file "SecureManifest.xml" under "assets" folder:
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File apkFile = new File(sdcard, "file.apk");
if (apkFile.exists()) {
    try {
        InputStream is =getInputStreamFromApkResource(apkFile.toString(), "assets/SecureManifest.xml");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(is));
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("***", str);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The github gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/simoneaonzo/eaf4e3e001a339d4e605)